# Active Record Query strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The situation is on the screenshot below:

[image]

As you see, I call `Property.limit(10)` to grab first 10 objects from the database, but the query will execute only if I call `@properties` variable. I don't understand why it is not called. It then will be called in the view and slow up rendering. Surprisingly,it will be called in `_filter` partial, however, it doesn't contain `@properties` variable at all. What's going on?

[image]

At the same time, `City.all` and `Country.all` are executed in the controller. How can it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Property.limit(10)` does not load 10 properties from the database like you expect. It only returns a [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html).

The database query happens when you call a method on that Relation object that actually needs the data from that database (like calling `count` or `each`).

This is default ActiveRecord behavior. It does not slow down anything, because it does not affect the overall response time if the data loaded in the controller or in the view.

Read more about [Relations and Lazy Evaluation](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-queries).

Comment: This is the reason why you can chain multiple active record queries and the way by which ActiveRecord is able to merge all the queries into a single query.